# Failing XHR in PhoneGap/Cordova + Android 4.1/4.2 + Samsung Hardware

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest, samsung-mobile

In the JavaScript below, the `reqListener` callback (used in the XHR call) never runs when used in a PhoneGap/Cordova app on Samsung hardware running Android 4.1 and Android 4.2. It works fine in Android 2.x and iOS. What am I doing wrong? (I hope it's something obvious. I'm OK feeling stupid about this if it means getting a fix.)

```
function reqListener (result) {
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('results');
    var resultText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
    if ("textContent" in resultElement) {
        resultElement.textContent = resultText;
    } else {
        resultElement.innerText = resultText;
    }
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open('GET', 'http://apis.ucsf.edu/shuttle/stops');
oReq.send();
```

Full source code of an app demonstrating the issue (if you want to look at the `config.xml` or build it on PhoneGap Build to see it work/not work for yourself) is at https://github.com/Trott/XHRBug. It's all stock stuff except the `index.html` and `config.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared my implementation with what ZeptoJS was doing and altered it to the code below, which now works with the Galaxy S4 + PhoneGap combination that was failing before.

I think the parts that did the trick were:

- avoiding `onload` and using `onreadystatechange` instead
- manually unsetting the readystatechange callback once it was fired with a readyState of 4

And now the code:

```
<title>Simple XHR Test</title>

<h1>Simple XHR Test</h1>
<p id="results">Running the simple XHR test...</p>

<script>
function reqListener (resultText) {
    var resultElement = document.getElementById('results');
    if ("textContent" in resultElement) {
        resultElement.textContent = resultText;
    } else {
        resultElement.innerText = resultText;
    }
};

var oReq = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
        oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {};
        reqListener(oReq.responseText);
    }
}
oReq.open('GET', 'http://apis.ucsf.edu/shuttle/stops');
oReq.send(null);
</script>
```